# Making tikz stricter about missing coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, error-writing

The following MWE compiles without errors or warnings and produces two tikz pictures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

A picture:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[draw] (b) at (1,0) {B};
    \draw (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}

Another picture:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[draw] (a) at (0,0) {A};
    \draw (a) -- (b); % note: coordinate (b) doesn't exist!
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I'm drawing a lot of complex diagrams and keep running into subtle problems because I don't realise I'm connecting to a coordinate that was defined in a previous diagram but not the current one.

In order to prevent this, I would really like compilation to halt with an error when this happens. Is there a way to make tikz stricter about this, so that such problems can be caught?

Comment: don't use `b`  you get an error for `c` or `Q` or ...

Comment: more exactly don't re-use names from the first picture

Comment: @DavidCarlisle there are currently about 140 diagrams in my document, most of them depicting different relationships between the same mathematical objects. Attempting to use distinct names for every instance wouldn't be practical, and indeed I would still need the same kind of error detection in order to make sure I hadn't done so by mistake.

Comment: @Rmano thank you, yes, I think that is a duplicate and the answer should work for me I think. (I've voted to close my own quesiton.)

Comment: sure, looks like a tikz ---bug---/feature to me, something is not being reset, comments just helping someone narrow down the cause. That said, using unique names wouldn't be that hard, just globall change `(..)` to `(\foo ..)` and arrange `\foo` has a different expansion in each tkz (eg via a counter).. oh `name prefix` in other comment does this internall

Comment: @DavidCarlisle probably can be automated with `name prefix` and a suitable `every picture` key, yes...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think it is a bug, it would be very hard if names were local (e.g. foreach loops would probably break).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer foreach having local scope is a bug:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, certainly odd. But there are lots of other scopes in tikz pictures, sometimes even on a path and you wouldn't want to have to struggle to get the node names out of them all the time. name prefix is really the way to go if you want unique names.

Comment: @Rmano luckily each of my diagrams is generated from the same set of macros, so I think I can automate the `name prefix` easily enough. Feel free to vote to reopen though, if you or someone else wants to post a nice general way to do the automation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes agreed, I was just working backwards through a tracingall diff of `(b)` and `(c)` the top level `name prefix` key would have been reached eventually but Rmano's comment faster